# Can we return json object from DAO layer?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dao

I read about DAO layer and as far as i know DAO layer should add data into the database and get data from the database.

While returning it should return POJOs.

Is it okay (legal) if DAO returns a JSON object or jsonArray without breaking the design pattern?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but I would not do that. Why do you think that might be a good idea? Why not return an actual object, with typed fields, useful methods, etc.

Comment: DAO stands for what it stands for, the nature of the data isn't proscribed. JSON is view-specific, however, and IMO that translation should happen after the data is retrieved.

Comment: I wanted to use jsonarray in the entire project for retrieving data. But yes i got it. Thanks.

Comment: Return POJO from DAO and serialize it to JSON at controller layer would more flexible solution. Think what if some services want to get your data in the format of XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, no.

DAO is a design pattern and it should return a simple POJOs which will be used by Service layer. Service can provide as simple entities to the end user, and JSON-objects and so on.

I hope it'll help. ;)

Comment: What is wrong if DAO deals with json annotated objects ?